# How get a max value from array of dictionaries with the same structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need get a max value of index from dictionary with the biggest index value. I guess this can be done by using function max() and lambda, but I don't know how do it correctly.

```
 data = [
    {'address': '499 Eastern Parkway',
      'city': 'Kenvil',
      'company': 'GONKLE',
      'country': 'India',
      'index': 0,
      'name': 'Shelby Gutierrez'},
     {'address': '552 Butler Place',
      'city': 'Rivereno',
      'company': 'FITCORE',
      'country': 'United States',
      'index': 1,
      'name': 'Jenny Cardenas'},
     {'address': '176 Pleasant Place',
      'city': 'Coultervillle',
      'company': 'CONFRENZY',
      'country': 'Sao Tome and Principe',
      'index': 2,
      'name': 'Boyer Austin'}
    ]
```

Comment: What do you mean? You mean that you want to return the dictionary  with the largest index?

Comment: not dictionary, just value of index in this dictionary with max index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def maxIndex(data):
    return max(d['index'] for d in data)

print(maxIndex(data))
```

The result is:

```
2
```

If you don't want to use loops, you can also do:

```
def maxIndexWithMap(data):
    return max(list(map(lambda i: i['index'], data)))

print(maxIndexWithMap(data))
```

The result again is:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the value you are looking for, then generator expresshon should do it:

```
max(d['index'] for d in data)
```